# Order regression variables in table using gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

Is it possible to order variables in a regression table using a `gtsummary` function? For example, let's say I have the following model:

```
model <- lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + drat + hp, data = mtcars)
```

I would like to create a regression table with the independent variables in the following order: **drat**, then **hp**, and then **disp**. The following code would accomplish that goal:

```
library(gtsummary)
lm(formula = mpg ~ drat + hp + disp, data = mtcars) |>
  tbl_regression()
```

But, rather than re-running the regression, I would like to reorder the variables contained in the `model` object. Is there a way to do this using a `gtsummary` function (or some other post-estimation function)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to re-order the variables, as you mentioned, is to re-run the model with the variables in the order you like. But this can be time consuming with large models.

In each gtsummary object there is a data frame called `.$table_body`. Essentially, gtsummary is a fancy print of this data frame and you can re-order the rows as you need.

There is a column in the data frame called variable, and you can sort whichever variables you'd like to the top or bottom. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter
library(dplyr)

model <- lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + drat + hp, data = mtcars) 

tbl_regression(model) %>%
  # re-order the variables in the table
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>%
      arrange(desc(variable == "hp")) %>%
      arrange(desc(variable == "drat"))
  ) %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable so it'll display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **Beta** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| drat | 2.7 | -0.33, 5.8 | 0.079 |
| hp | -0.03 | -0.06, 0.00 | 0.027 |
| disp | -0.02 | -0.04, 0.00 | 0.050 |

<sup>Created on 2021-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>